# ICustomRouter interface >> CSOM or Server Side Object model

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, ssom

We are looking into a custom document route, and I know about the ICustomRouter interface.
Can it be used in CSOM?

The ICustomeRouter example here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.recordsmanagement.recordsrepository.icustomrouter.aspx

references:
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

...which leans towards the Server Side Object model.

I don't see anything for "routing" or "records" here for the 2013 API:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn268594(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn268594%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand your query, ICustomRouter  is still there in Sharepoint 2013 Server Object model as per following link :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/microsoft.office.recordsmanagement.recordsrepository.icustomrouter.aspx

As this is related to document routing, I don't think there is equivalent API available in CSOM. So can use Sharepoint server object model for this.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  So in order for us to create a custom document loader with the ICustomRouter interface, we'll need to use the Server Object Model...correct?

Comment: Yes. Use server object model